# Translating python2 itertools.izip to python3 zip

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in the process of translating my python2 code to python3

One error I am getting is that I need to replace itertools.izip with zip

I did that but I am still getting errors.

I found that these two functions are not really equivalent. Here is an example:

```
from itertools import izip
for a,b in izip(range(3), "ABC"):
  print(a,b)
```

The above script gave me the following outputounder python2:

```
(0, 'A')
(1, 'B')
(2, 'C')
```

If I simply replace izip with zip and run under python3:

```
for a,b in zip(range(3),"ABC"):
  print(a,b)
```

The output I got is different:

```
0 A
1 B
2 C
```

How do I fix my python2 code such that it will generate the same output as before? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: `print((a, b))`? In Python 2 you printed a tuple. In Python 3 you're printing two elements separated with a space

Comment: The root of the problem here is not really `zip`/`izip`, but rather the change of `print` from a keyword to a function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you observe isn't caused by the zipping, but by the `print` function/statement.

In Python 2, it has this syntax:

```py
print x, ...
```

In Python 3, it has this syntax:

```py
print(x, ...)
```

Thus in Python 2, `print(a,b)` prints the one argument, tuple `(a,b)`. In Python 3, `print(a,b)` prints the two arguments `a` and `b` separately, separated by the default separator (space).

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your code with [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) and [modernize](https://python-modernize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tools could be faster and less error-prone. And now is the right time to start writing tests because *print* is not a best tool to assert the values.